# iterate JSON, swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I am working on swift.
The response that I get from the web server is different when i test it on Postman/ browser and mobile emulator.

**Postman/browser response :**

```
items: [
    {
    itemId: 500,
    name: "ABC"
    },
    {
    itemId: 500,
    name: "ABC"
    }
    ]
```

**Response in iOS :**

```
 items: (
    {
    itemId: 500,
    name: "ABC"
    },
    {
    itemId: 500,
    name: "ABC"
    }
    )
```

I would like to know how to iterate through the array, but since the result is not an `array` on iOS I am not sure on how should I go about it. Also, I retrieve a result of around 25-30 items in the `array`. I have a some set of variables too, that are provided in the response after the array.

Comment: Why do you say it's not an array? It's an array of dictionaries. Don't conflate Swift syntax with JSON syntax or with the way objects are printed, which is only a representation, not the object itself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with your response in `ios` when you print an array it will print with `()` brackets instead of `[]` brackets and dictionary will be print with `{}` braces.

As you say `let items : [NSDictionary]!` your items array contain `dictionary` then you can iterate it like this

```
for item in items {
    print(item["itemId"])
    print(item["name"])
}
```

Comment: `let items : [NSDictionary]!
var items : [NSDictionary]!
httpresponsefunc(){

  self.items = response["items"] as! [NSDictionary]

}`
Is this what you saying?

Comment: @sau123 this will print like `({}, {} ...)`

Comment: Yes, I get that, it will print like this.

What I would like to know is, how should we iterate through it?

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your response in iOS is fine.

You can iterate over it simply with:

```
for item in items {

// do what you want with each item

}
```

It works fine in a Playground:

```
let items = [["itemId": 500, "name" : "ABC"], [ "itemId": 500, "name": "ABC"]] as NSArray


for item in items {
    print(item as! NSDictionary) // prints each dictionary as expected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of dictionaries. So, you can iterate like-

```
for itemDict in items {
    let itemId = itemDict["itemId"]
    println("Item ID: \(itemId)")

    let name = itemDict["name"]
    println("Item name: \(name)")
}
```

Comment: This won't work given that `println` has been removed. Additionally, this will print "Item ID: Optional(500)".